# Two same ADCs produce different result for same signal

Tags: adc

I have two [ADC](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9248.pdf)s (the model `AD9248BST/BCP-65`, with the default configurations, not "cross-calibrated"), that are feed the same constant point-to-point voltage. The returned values, however, differ by an order of 7 bits.

The datasheet (see page 3) specifies that the effective number of bits is 11.8, so I should expect noise in the difference to be of the order of 2.2 + 1 = 3.2 bits.

What could explain that the difference between the two ADCs is greater than expected?

Comment: Seven bits as in 0 - 127 or seven counts as in 0-6? Are you sure both ADC's have their conversion finished? Do you have a schematic diagram, a photo of your set up and a listing of the program you use? Show us what you're doing.

Comment: Seven bits, as in 0 - 127. The conversion should be finished as I'm keeping the voltage constant and reading the value a few times a second with the error persisting.

Comment: I didn't check the datasheet, but every ADC is able to flag you when it finishes conversion. If you read the value too quickly after starting conversion, you'll get wrong readings. You can usually poll a status register or receive an interrupt on completion. Do you have a schematic diagram, a photo of your set up and a listing of the program you use? Show us what you're doing.

Comment: @jippie - a flash ADC such as this one generally just spits the data out (usually a few cycles delay) with no other indication (i.e. data changes on rising/falling edge of each clock cycle - datasheet will specify when stable to read)

Comment: @OliGlaser - I was being lazy and I probably should have checked the datasheet ... My other requests about schematic, photo, listing are still valid in my opinion though

Comment: @Randomblue did you try swap the IC and check if the same reading persist?

Comment: @JeeShenLee: What do you mean by "swap the IC"?

Comment: @Randomblue you mentioned you have 2 ADC with diff reading, i'm suggesting to swap the 2 ICs while keeping other parts of the circuit intact. Then, check if the reading persist.

Comment: @JeeShenLee: The IC2 are soldered to my board, can't move them.

Comment: As far as such ADCs are concerned the PCB layout, ground layout, noise, the way input voltage fed to the input pins, power supply quality all these factors are very very important. Unless you supply the schematic and may be photo of your setup, it is hard to provide technically correct answer. So if it is possible do provide the same.

Comment: @Randomblue - Swapping the ADCs is a very good approach. If they're expensive, then don't do it. Otherwise, carefully remove them both. If you can do it without physically damaging them, otherwise solder on two new ones.

Comment: @Randomblue - Please can you post a schmatic *and* a screen shot of the PCB layout?

Comment: Is the error systematic or random? Are you reading both ADCs at the same time or at different moment? Are you very very sure there is no noise on the input or on the ground? Does the error scale (get lower with lower input voltage)?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: The error is systematic. I'm reading both ADCs at the same time. The inputs are the same. The error does not seem to scale.

Comment: A systematic error that does not scale suggest a ground difference.

Comment: @Randomblue - Please can you post a schmatic and a screen shot of the PCB layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a very large number of error sources in the data sheet.
 Some are mutually inclusive, some are not.
 There are 3 IC variants in the data sheet with different error levels and you do not say which you are using.

You do not say what the input voltage is or what voltage reference you are using or if you have cross calibrated these devices in any way.
 Assuming 1V in pp and internal reference in own IC in each case then reference error is +/- 5 mV typical and +/- 35 mV worst case. 5 mV in 1V is 1:200 or about 1.2 bits in an 8 bit system or about 7 bits in a 14 bit system, and the worst case 35 mV is log_2(35/5)  ~= 3 bits worse again = 10 bits, so "only" 7 bits, before we look at  the other error sources seems "good" [tm].

It may be that you are sharing a reference (if not, do try it) or calibrating for reference or other errors or whatever, but if so you need to tell us.

Comment: I have the `AD9248BST/BCP-65` variant, and the high level of error seems to persist regardless of the voltage level I provide. What do you mean by "cross calibrate"? What are the various ways to cross calibrate the ADCs? Why are the error margins you calculate much larger than the "Effective Number of Bits" they provide?

Comment: @Randomblue - the accuracy of the converter and the accuracy and stability of its reference are independent unless stated otherwise. Using the same reference voltage source for both converters would eliminate this as a relative error source. By cross calibrate I meant to not just calibrate each one against a standard but to adjust so mutual results at say max and half readings are the same and 0=0. What are you using for the voltage reference? Internal reference in each case? If you read Vref1 with ADC2 and Vref2 with ADC1 what do you get? (Vrefx with ADCx is always perfect - even when wrong).